# Al imprimir 2 cadenas guardadas en un struct, desaparecen

Tags: c, punteros, struct, registro

tengo una función que llena 2 datos de una estructura: un código y un nombre de asignatura. Los lleno manual, cada una de las posiciones. Cuando lleno todos los nombres los imprime sin problema, pero cuando lleno los códigos, desaparecen, no tengo idea por que, podrían ayudarme a saber que estoy haciendo mal por favor.

ESTRUCTURA

```
typedef struct{
char nombre[30];
char matricula[8];
Calificaciones listaCalificaciones[60]; }Alumno;
```

FUNCION DE LLENADO

```
void cardex(Alumno *a)
{
    strcpy(a->listaCalificaciones[0].nombre,"Algebra superior");
    strcpy(a->listaCalificaciones[1].nombre,"Base de datos");
    strcpy(a->listaCalificaciones[2].nombre,"Física aplicada a las ciencias de la computación");
    
    strcpy(a->listaCalificaciones[0].codigo,"LISC01");
    strcpy(a->listaCalificaciones[1].codigo,"LISC02");
    strcpy(a->listaCalificaciones[2].codigo,"LISC03");
}
```

FUNCIÓN DE IMPRESIÓN

```
void imprimirHistorial(Alumno a)
{
    int i;
    printf("--------HISTORIAL ACADEMICO--------\n");
    printf("Calificacion\t\tAsignatura\n");
    for(i=0;i<59;i++)
    {
        printf("%.2f\t%s\t%s\n",a.listaCalificaciones[i].calif,a.listaCalificaciones[i].codigo, a.listaCalificaciones[i].nombre);
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que debería ser `for(i = 0; i < 60; i++)`

Comment: Sin muchos detalles en el código, no se puede entender.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código de `Calificaciones` ?